# Java error (Cannot find symbol)

Tags: java

```
package aa;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import aa.*;
import aa.Mapper;
import aa.Reducer;

/**
 * Some example code on how to use the MapReduce Framework
 */
public class Example2 implements Mapper, Reducer
{
}
```

The following error I get below. I am unsure what is the error. I have included the Mapper and Reducer in the same package already.

```
Example2.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import aa.Mapper;
         ^
  symbol:   class Mapper
  location: package aa
Example2.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
import aa.Reducer;
         ^
  symbol:   class Reducer
  location: package aa
Example2.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
```

Comment: do the filenames match the class/interface names?  show the code and filename for Mapper and Reducer, as well as the full output from where you try to compile

Answer (score 0):

Your class is in the same package of Mapper and Reducer. 
**You don't need to import them.**

Comment: But I still get the following error, Example2.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
public class Example2 implements Mapper, Reducer
                                 
  symbol: class Mapper
Example2.java:13: error: cannot find symbol

Comment: Do you have put Mapper and Reducer in two different files (Mapper.java and Reducer.java) in the **same directory** of Example2.java ?

Comment: I got my answer from here already, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998053/cannot-find-symbol-for-my-own-class

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have all your class files in your classpath? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your class is in same directory, so no need to import them. Check your class files of `Mapper` and `Reducer`, whether they reside inside `aa` directory.