# How do I call a method from another class?

Tags: java, bluej

I want to print a method that is in another class. How do I do that?

Thanks!

The method name I am trying to call is 
`public void printMenu()...` within a class called `FoodMenu`.

Comment: You can also use friend function.
It can be helpful => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226228/implementation-of-friend-concept-in-java

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please take some time to read the how to ask a good question guide. I will help you get better answers in te future. :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Create an instance of `FoodMenu` and use it to call `printMenu()`

```
FoodMenu foodMenu = new FoodMenu();
foodMenu.printMenu();
```

Comment: Thanks! I did this and an error message came "can't find class symbol"

Comment: @JenFisher There might be problem with the compilation. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7373255/5168011) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5998081/5168011)

Answer (score 0):

You will need an object of the class **FoodMenu** 
 then you can call the method

Do someting like:

```
FoodMenu myFoodMenu = new FoodMenu(); // declaring the object
myFoodMenu .printMenu(); // calling the method.
```

if your class **FoodMenu** is in another package, then import it in the class you are going to define the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class FoodMenu{
    public void printMenu() { 
    System.out.println("here is menu sir!"); 

}
     public static void main(String[] arg) {
    FoodMenu f = new FoodMenu();
    f.printMenu();
    }
    }
```

`FoodMenu` object created by `new` keyword
And with help of object you can call its method `f.printMenu();`